# Auth0: Conditional multi-factor rule removes permissions from JWT

Tags: react-native, permissions, jwt, auth0, multi-factor-authentication

For some reason enabling MFA (sms code) removes permissions from JWT (access token). I have checked the setup a few times and all seems to be OK, but for the same account without MFA a permissions presented in JWT, with enabled MFA - no. (I do not using `webauth`)

I have found this 3 topics:

- [Access token is missing permissions when using MFA](https://community.auth0.com/t/access-token-is-missing-permissions-when-using-mfa/48277)
- [Permissions not included in access token for MFA flow](https://community.auth0.com/t/permissions-not-included-in-access-token-for-mfa-flow/57736)
- [Conditional multi-factor rule removes permissions from JWT](https://community.auth0.com/t/conditional-multi-factor-rule-removes-permissions-from-jwt/35403)

And I think we have the same kind of problem (there is no answer by links).

Code of rule looks like this:

```
    const userEnrolledFactors = user.multifactor || [];
    const canPromptMfa = userEnrolledFactors.length > 0;

    if(canPromptMfa) {
      context.multifactor = {
        provider: "any",
        allowRememberBrowser: false,
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was on `Auth0` side. And now it have been **fixed** on their side
[image]